# preventing user from saving file from website but allow him to print it

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, printing

I am working with a client who has a business of selling a genre of PDF files online and so he wants a functionality for his website where users can print the files but not be able to download it as PDF so as to prevent further distribution by users.
Is there any way by which I can give a print option in a website but users should not be able to download that file and just print it. I personally think this is kind of difficult as most browsers while handling a print command give the option to save the file as PDF.
I hope there is some way around it using javascript or some specialized javascript library.

Comment: If it's available for print, it's available for download as it has to be downloaded to print.

Comment: I don't actually think that's possible with a PDF as once the user has it opened up the PDF on their browser, it's already been downloaded.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the document can always be easily downloaded by rightclicking, printing to onenote, or even wget. Printers sometimes even keep copies of the file.

Comment: Let's say you _could_ do this (which you can't). The user could just scan what they printed. They would then have a digital copy. This isn't going to prevent anything.

Comment: That's what even i thought of but I had a responsibility to at least try once for a solution as a part of fulfilment of clients demands. As I am a newbie I thought I could use some help if possible. Thanks to all anyways.

Comment: Thats like ordering a coke without water

Comment: It's beyond the scope of what javascript is capable of, however you could write an activex control or java applet to pipe raw data straight to the printer port. Bear  in mind that anyone serious about wanting to make a copy can just use OCR software to scan it back as a pdf, which renders any server side protection you put in place redundant =s

Comment: I like your suggestion @MichaelWhinfrey. I will surely do some research to see if I can actually so something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. What you print is what you download and therfor can be saved.

The only way I can think of to make it harder for the user to share the original PDF, is some server side service rendering the PDFs as images and serving those on a website which can be printed out. Of course the user could still save those images, but it wouldn't be in a PDF Format.

Comment: Okay Thanks for reply though.

Answer (score 0):

His best bet is to Watermark his files. Print dialog boxes now offer the option to "Print To PDF" & "Print to XPS", etc so a native ability to stop people from saving his files is not an option. I would suggest he watermark his files, that way at least his mark is on every page of all the documents.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can encrypt the file or add a password to open it.